# laplace transformation $\cos^2(3t)$ and $\sin(5t)cos(2t)$

Tags: integration, derivatives, laplace-transform

it is asked to transform  $\cos^2(3t)$ and $\sin(5t)cos(2t)$ using the results from [image: laplace transformation table]

i think the process might be similar for both of them but i don't know wich result to use.

can you help me?

thanks

Comment: Hint: can you use trig identities to put your two functions into a form which enables you to use the table?

Comment: oh...yes i was trying to use 14 but i don't know how to use it. i will try with your hint. thanks

Comment: @Mark Bennet i got it! thanks! would it be possible to use 14? if so, would you mind to tell me how?