# Why is it that the Laplace transform of $f(t)$ evaluated at $s = j\omega$ is not the Fourier transform

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

> Many [sources](https://www.quora.com/Signal-Processing-What-are-the-differences-between-Laplace-and-Fourier-Transform) state that the Laplace transform is simply the Fourier
>   transform where $\text{Re}(s) =0 \implies s = j\omega$
>
> However, why is it that substituting $s = j\omega$ into Laplace
>   transforms of a function $f(t)$ do not yield the corresponding Fourier transform (for large number of
>   transforms)?

For example,

The laplace transform of $\sin(\omega_o t)$ is $$\dfrac{\omega_o}{s^2 + \omega_o^2}$$

(According to [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091868/laplace-transformation-cos23t-and-sin5tcos2t))

Where as the fourier transform yields:

$$i\pi (\delta(\omega+\omega_o) - \delta(\omega-\omega_o))$$

(According to [source](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/prove-fourier-transform-table-modern-digital-analog-communication-systems-bp-lathi-q3668478))

But evaluating $$\dfrac{\omega_o}{s^2 + \omega_o^2}|_{s = i\omega} = \dfrac{\omega_o}{-\omega^2 + \omega_o^2}$$

Quite the *stark* contrast.

**When does the Fourier transform and the Laplace transform coincide for $s = j\omega$**

**Why is that sometimes they do not coincide?**

Comment: The Laplace transform is one-sided (it is given by an integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}$) while the Fourier transform is not, so the given equivalence only holds for functions with a special simmetry.

Comment: There's a discussion about this on the Wiki page for Laplace transforms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Fourier_transform). The upshots seem to be 1) one needs to work with the _bilateral_ Laplace transform, not the _unilateral_ version, 2) there can still be issues arising from convergence on the imaginary axis.

Comment: The Laplace transform $\mathscr{L}(f)(is)$ evaluated on the imaginary axis is the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(s)$ of the given function $f$ truncated to $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: The (one sided) Laplace transform $F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st}dt$ is the bilateral Laplace transform of $f(t)1_{t > 0}$, itself the Fourier transform of $f(t)e^{-\sigma t} 1_{t > 0}$ evaluated at $\omega$, where $s= \sigma+i \omega$. That's exactly why they should stop teaching the one-sided Laplace transform.